# cypress- Sends data from a page to an other page (new tab)

Tags: javascript, button, tabs, cypress, send

I have a button that opens an new tab. I know the url and I can use `cy.visit()`.

This is what I have in the button:

```
input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btbRenew" value="Renew"
id="btbRenew" class="btn" style="float: right;"
```

My problem is that normally the pop-up opens with data from the button page.
If I use `cy.visit()`, I don't have any data in the newly opened page.

Any ideas how I can send data from the first page to the second page?